# Calling a function from an object with dir()

Tags: python

Using the `dir` call, I can see the following functions in an object

```
>>> dir(my_action)
['NameBase_DEMANGLED', 'NameBase_FUNCTION', 'NameBase_MANGLED', 
'__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', 
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', 
'__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', 
'__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', 
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__swig_destroy__', 
'__weakref__', 'add_double_metric', 'add_integer_metric', 
'add_string_metric', 'metric_by_name', 'metric_names', 'name', 
'nvtx_state', 'ptx_by_pc', 'sass_by_pc', 'source_files', 
'source_info', 'this', 'thisown']
```

If I use `name`, there is no problem

```
>>> my_action.name()
'binning_kernel'
```

However, using another function returns the following error

```
>>> my_action.NameBase_DEMANGLED()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Is the error related to bad syntax?

Comment: NameBase_DEMANGLED is an integer which is not callable

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not related to bad syntax.

It's related to the fact that `NameBase_DEMANGLED` is an integer, and you can't call integers.

You'd get a similar error trying to do `my_action.__doc__()`, since `__doc__` is the docstring of the action, a string.

`dir()` shows you everything in the given object, including e.g. class fields, instance fields, etc. You can use `callable()` to figure out if a given object is callable.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out hat `my_action.name(1)` is `NameBase_DEMANGLED`.